# R: coin::wilcoxsign_test() distribution = "exact"

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

In a repeated measure design, I have two measurements for one variable for *N*=5 subjects. I am interested in assessing whether the distribution of the differences between the two measurements is symmetrical around zero. For this reason, I am performing a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test with `wilcox.test()` in **R**.

However, due to a zero in my differences, I am warned in **R** that I cannot get an exact *p*-value. The warning I get is:

`Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x, y, paired = TRUE) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes`

More specifically, what I am understanding is that a continuity correction will be applied to my *p*-value since my *T* statistic will be compared against a normal approximation of the *T* distribution. Am I understanding this correctly? I am understanding that similarly this happens also when there are ties in the difference values.

Moreover, due to the low numerosity of my sample, I understand that approximating the *T* distribution to a normal one is not the ideal solution, so I am shifting to the `wilcoxsign_test()` function from the `coin` package. By using the `distribution = "exact"` argument, it seems to me that the `wilcoxsign_test()` function will compare the *T* statistic computed on my data against the *T* distribution computed by permuting *all* my data. Is this correct?
Moreover, handling of ties (and zeroes?) will be carried out according to the Pratt (1959) method (default). Am I correct?

Finally, does the `distribution = "asymptotic"` argument correspond to perform a normal approximation?

Comment: Exclude the cases with difference = 0.

Comment: Continuity  correction doesn't really relate to ties; continuity correction may be applied when using a continuous approximation to the null-distribution of the test statistic  because the statistic itself is discrete.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for your reply. What if I use the `distribution = "exact"` argument in the `coin::wilcoxsign_test()`? In my understanding this will permute my samples and estimate the T distribution under the null hypothesis. Then (still in my understanding) my data's T value will be compared against this null distribution and I will get a p-value accordingly. Is this that happens with the `distribution = "exact"` argument? If so I guess that no continuity correction will be applied.

Comment: @a_statistician , wouldn't you advise using the Pratt or Wilcoxon correction for zero differences rather than excluding those cases?

Comment: Your situation is very similar to what the McNemar test. On McNemar test, if A = B then the case will be excluded, because this case does not give you any information.

Comment: @mariamelie If you're using the permutation distribution there'd be no reason to apply a continuity correction.

Comment: @mariamelie , I think your instinct is right that using the `wilcoxsign_test` function with the `exact` option is probably the most appropriate approach in this case. With your small *n*, it's easy to try some different data with the different tests.  I think you'll find that using either a) the *exact* option or b) the *asymptotic* option with the Pratt correction, yield similar results.  Using c) `wilcox.test` with the continuity correction is also reasonably similar, and appears to get more conservative if there zeros when *n* is greater.  Upshot:  It's probably not worrying too much about.

Answer (score 3):

There are several questions here.  I will attempt to assemble some the comments and my own thoughts into an answer.  A caveat here is that I'm not entirely familiar with the programming of these functions, so there may be misconceptions in the following answer.

Note that this question pertains to the paired or one-sample tests.

*Warning*.  The warning message from `wilcox.test` doesn't imply that the test results are invalid.  It merely means what it says:  The test can't compute an exact *p*-value when there are zero differences.  Instead it will remove the zeros and compute the *p*-value by asymptotic approximation. The following two calls give the same result:

`wilcox.test(c(0,1,2,3,4), exact=F)`

`wilcox.test(c(1,2,3,4), exact=F`

*Continuity correction*: The continuity correction is applied only when the *p*-value is computed by asymptotic approximation. So the following give the same result:

`wilcox.test(c(1,2,3,4), exact=T, correct=F)`

`wilcox.test(c(1,2,3,4), exact=T, correct=T)`

but the following give different results:

`wilcox.test(c(1,2,3,4), exact=F, correct=F)`

`wilcox.test(c(1,2,3,4), exact=F, correct=T)`

I'm pretty sure the `wilcoxsign_test` function never applies the continuity correction.

*Handling of zero differences*: As mentioned above, when there are zero differences, the `wilcox.test` function removes those zeros, and uses the asymptotic approximation for the *p*-value.

The `wilcoxsign_test` function can compute an "exact" *p*-value when there are zero differences.  For example,

`wilcoxsign_test(c(0,0,0,0,0)~c(0,1,2,3,4), distribution="exact")`.

The `wilcoxsign_test` function can handle zero differences in two ways, so that the following give different results: *Pratt* and *Wilcoxon*:

`wilcoxsign_test(c(0,0,0,0,0)~c(0,1,2,3,4), distribution="approximate", zero.method="Pratt")`

`wilcoxsign_test(c(0,0,0,0,0)~c(0,1,2,3,4), distribution="approximate", zero.method="Wilcoxon")`

But I don't think these methods differ if *distribution="exact"* is used. I'm not sure.

With `wilcoxsign_test`, I think using *distribution="asymptotic"* and *zero.method="Wilcoxon"* will result in the same handling as would `wilcox.test`, so that the following two give the same result:

`wilcoxsign_test(c(0,0,0,0,0)~c(0,1,2,3,4), distribution="asymptotic", zero.method="Wilcoxon")`

`wilcox.test(c(0,1,2,3,4), exact=F, correct=F)`